# javascript validateform() function not validating form

Tags: javascript, html

When I enter invalid details the website doesn't show up with any errors and it sumbits the form

I've tried putting onsubmit on the form tag and onclick on the button tag but nothing works

it should come up with an error when I type in an invalid email or postcode or the passwords dont match

also I would like it so that when the  user inputs numbers for the first name or last name it comes up with an error

```html
  <form  class="modal-content" action="register.php" method="post"  name="myform">
                            <div class="signup-container">()
                                <h1>Sign Up</h1>
                                <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
                                <hr>
                                <div class="fbox">
                                    <label for="fn"><b style="font-size:14px;">First Name</b></label>
                                    <input type="text" id= "First_Name" placeholder="Enter First Name" name="fname" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="sbox">
                                    <label for="ln"><b style="font-size:14px;">Last Name</b></label>
                                    <input type="text" id= "Last_Name" placeholder="Enter Last Name" name="lname" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tbox">
                                    <label for="email"><b style="font-size:14px;">Email</b></label>
                                    <input type="text" id="Email" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="fobox">
                                    <label for="pc"><b style="font-size:14px;">Post Code</b></label>
                                    <input type="text" id="pcode" placeholder="Postcode" name="pcode" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="fibox">
                                    <label for="psw"><b style="font-size:14px;">Password</b></label>
                                    <input type="password" id="pass" placeholder="Enter Password" name="pass" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="sixbox">
                                    <label for="psw"><b style="font-size:14px;">Confirm Password</b></label>
                                    <input type="password" id="UserPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="UserPassword" required>
                                </div>
                                <label class="remember">
                                    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
                                </label>
                                <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="#" style="color:dodgerblue">Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>
                                <div class="clearfix">
                                    <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
                                    <button onclick="validateform()"type="submit" name="Submit" class="signupbtn">Sign Up</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

```js
<script>

  function validateform(){
var Firstname = document.querySelector( "#First_name"); //sets the variable name as the value entered by the user
var Lastname = document.querySelector( "#Last_Name"); //sets the variable name as the value entered by the user
var password = document.querySelector( "#pass");//sets the variable password as the value entered by the user
var confirmpassword = document.querySelector( "#UserPassword");//sets the variable confirmpassword as the value entered by the user
var email = document.querySelector( "#Email");//sets the variable email as the value entered by the user
var atposition = email.indexOf("@");
var dotposition = email.lastIndexOf(".");
var postcode = document.querySelector("pcode");//sets the variable postcode as the value entered by the user
function alertMessage(messageObject) {
    alert(messageObject);
    return true;
}
if (Firstname==null){
  alertMessage("Firstname can't be blank");  //makes sure that the name is not empty
  return false;
}else if (Lastname==null){
  alertMessage("Lastname can't be blank");  //makes sure that the name is not empty
  return false}


else if (atposition<1 || dotposition<atposition+2 || dotposition+2>=email.length){
  alertMessage("Please enter a valid e-mail address \n atpostion:"+atposition+"\n dotposition:"+dotposition);  //makes sure email is in the right format
  return false;
  }
function valid_postcode(postcode){
    postcode = postcode.replace(/\s/g, "");
    var regex = /^[A-Z]{1,2} ?[0-9][A-Z]{2}$/i;
    return regex.test(postcode);

}
valid_postcode(postcode)



 if(password.length<8){
  alertMessage("Password must be at least 8 characters long.");  //makes sure password is above 8 characters
  return false;
  }
else if(password!==confirmpassword){
alertMessage("password must be same!");  //makes sure that the passwords match
return false;
}
}
```

Comment: `"index.php"."myform"."fname".value` what is this? There is nothing in javascript like this. Moreover there are multiple elements with same Id which is not a best practice

Comment: isnt that used to get the data from the form

Comment: No I don't think so. If you need a particular element's value, you should select that particular `DOM` element and then get its value. You can refer [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_object_model/Locating_DOM_elements_using_selectors)

Comment: ive replaced "index.php"."myform"."fname".value; with  document.querySelector( "#First_name"); and it still doesnt work

Comment: For that you need to analyse the second part of my first comment

Comment: ive changed the id's so that they are not the same but it still doesnt work

Comment: Please update your question with your code changes

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 0):

You should change your html type code from "submit" to "button", for the page not submit by it self. And put a id="myform" in your form.

```
<form  class="modal-content" action="register.php" method="post"  name="myform" id="myform">

<button onclick="validateform()" type="button" name="Submit" class="signupbtn">Sign Up</button>
```

And put this code on your javascript, you could do a verification to check if everything is ok, then you call this function to submit your form.

javacript

```
    document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
```

Comment: I changed the html and the javascript but it still doesnt work, where exactly do i put the  document.getElementById('myForm').submit();

Comment: you could do an "if" to check is your verification is true. If that's true you could execute that code